# Unable to resolve module `../setupBabel After upgrading react-native project and running on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I ran the upgrader by following [these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html). Then after trying to launch the project on android, by running "react-native run-android", the React Packager terminal window popped up and gave the following error. The app loaded on my android phone, but just said there was a 500 error on the server. Which I assume is coming from this error as the root cause.

What seems odd about this is that setupBabel.js is a file, and it is there in the correct folder, but this error says no such directory, not file. That's a bit odd...

```
React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `../setupBabel` from `/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/index.js`: Directory /Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/setupBabel doesn't exist
    at ResolutionRequest._loadAsDir (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:572:13)
    at tryResolveSync (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:411:18)
    at tryResolveSync (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:89:12)
    at ResolutionRequest._resolveFileOrDir (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:409:12)
    at ResolutionRequest._resolveNodeDependency (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:417:19)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:135:29)
    at dependencyNames.map.name (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:142:59)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveModuleDependencies (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:142:42)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/amato/git_react-native-web-hello-world/react-native-web-hello-world/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:179:21)
Bundling `index.js`  0.0% (0/20), failed.
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeWebHelloWorld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "ios-bundle": "react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle",
    "ios-dev-bundle": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle",
    "android-bundle": "react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --platform android --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle",
    "android-dev-bundle": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.android.js --platform android --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle",
    "web-bundle": "webpack --config web/webpack/web.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "web-dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors",
    "clear-cache": "gulp clear-cache",
    "react-start": "cd web; react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "clone": "^1.0.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.6",
    "mobx": "^3.0.0",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.0-rc.1",
    "react-redux": "^3.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "superagent": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native-cli": "^0.1.10",
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
    "redux-logger": "^2.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    'babel-polyfill',
    path.join(__dirname, '../../app/web/index'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // take all less files, compile them, and bundle them in with our js bundle
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less' 
      },{
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json",
      },{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
          plugins: [['react-transform', {
            transforms: [{
              transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
              imports: ['react'],
              // this is important for Webpack HMR:
              locals: ['module']
            }],
          }]],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        PLATFORM_ENV: JSON.stringify('web'),
      },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: can you share your webpack.config.js

Comment: It's in the second code box. shared in the main post

Comment: I meant webpack.config

Comment: Oh okay, I added the webpack.config file